# How to set default time in xdsoft datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I need to set a default time when selecting a date from the datetime picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the xdsoft documentation: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#defaultTime

`{defaultTime:'05:00'}`